# Remove all child Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a Fragment, which xml contains something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/myFragmen1"
            android:name="com...widgets.myViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text""/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I need to add 4 different fragments in my xml. The parent fragment I start like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, myFragment1)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

So, all works fine, till I'm trying to show the fragment more than 1 time. If I click back and trying to open the fragment again, then I'm getting these err:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #17: Duplicate id 0x7f080130, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com...widgets.myViewPager
```

I know the problem and also have a solution. I could remove the fragment in the onDestroy. But, this I don't wanna do!
The xml which contains the other fragment, is dynamically. I'm getting the layout through the bundle, so in this fragment I can't know, which fragment is shown. And if I'm using this part more than 1 time, i have to be sure, that the name is the same. So my question is: Is there any possibility to remove the in each fragment? So that every fragment removes himself and the parent have nothing to do?

Thanks for help

EDIT:

```
    MyFragment myFragment1 = new MyFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("layout",R.layout.my_fragment);
    myFragment1.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, myFragment1)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

These call I'm doing from different places. For each call can I make a own xml with the different fragments. 
And in my parent Fragment I'm doing this:

```
    int layoutId = this.getArguments().getInt("layout", 0);
    if(layoutId==0)
        throw new RuntimeException("LayoutId not found");

    return inflater.inflate(layoutId,container,false);
```

After doing that, my fragment load the xml with all the fragments, which I set in the xml. So can I define the view from outside. After destroy from this fragment and reopen it, it will throw the error. This is, because all the fragments in my xml are not destroyed! My parent fragment don't know, which fragments are in the xml, so I want, that they destroy himself in their class.

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because child `Fragment`s can only be created & displayed programmatically. The XML layout of a `Fragment` cannot contain a `<fragment ... />` tag. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

`You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.`

Here's what you need to do:

**STEP 1:** Modify the parent `Fragment`'s XML layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp">

    <!-- <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragmen1"
        android:name="com...widgets.myViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/childfragmentregion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**STEP 2:** Then, for swapping new child fragments:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.childfragmentregion, new SomeXYZFragment(), "some_xyz_fragment");
ft.commit();
```

**STEP 3:** Override your parent `Fragment`'s `onDetach()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This will work without exceptions. I request you to clarify the second part of your question: it is not clear to me which `Fragment` is getting data in a `Bundle`. I can help you further if you make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I think, this will not help. Maybe I should explain it a little bit better: I have 4 Fragments, which contains just a simple content, like 2 Textviews,... Next Comment, is too long for one comment :)

Comment: Now I just need to make an xml, which contains just the fragments, which I'm needed. I'm doing it like this, because I have some different places from where I will show the fragment, but have another content. So I just create a xml with the fragments und put these xml in the bundle. On start the fragment loads the xml with the different fragments. So I can handle the content of the view from outside, but don't have to care about the data, which should show.

Comment: I have merely pointed out the cause of the error, which I believe is correct. And I dont quite understand what you mean by "put xml in a bundle". What you mean, I take it, is that you are passing the string *value* of the `TextView`s in the child `Fragment`s in `Bundle`s.

Comment: For each place, from where I want to call the fragment, I'm creating a xml, which contains my fragments (like the xml in my question). Then I put the layoutId of the xml in the bundle and inflate then these xml. I'm edit my question, I hope it will help you to understand